# MongoDb C# Driver 2.0 add item to nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have a `Profiles` document collection with array of the following documents :

```
public class Profile2MailList
{


    [BsonElement(elementName: "listId")]
    [BsonRequired]
    public int MailListId;

    [BsonElement(elementName: "status")]
    [BsonRequired]
    public int Status;

    [BsonElement(elementName: "subscriptionDate")]
    [BsonRequired]
    public DateTime SubscriptionDate;
}
```

in each `Profile`.
I need to add to the `Profile2MailList` array a new `Profile2MailList` document in each `Profile` based on `Profile2MailList` which already contains in a certain `Profile`. So i need to

- Take needed profiles from `Profiles` collection
- Update
  `Profile2Maillist` array in each `Profile`
- Run update command
  How can i perform that action via `C# 2.0 MongoDb Driver`. I have `MongoDb v 3.0.2`.
  I try to make it by the following way :

  ```
     List<Profile> listProfiles = new List<Profile>();
              foreach (Profile item in profiles)
              {
                  item.MailLists.ToList().Add(new Profile2MailList(maillistId, item.MailLists.FirstOrDefault().Status));
                  var t = item;
                  listProfiles.Add(t);
              }
      dbCollection.UpdateManyAsync(listProfiles)
  ```

Comment: I know the changes in the new C# driver are poorly documented, but you must have at least tried something. Please show your attempt at this ( even if it fails ) as without it this just looks like a "write my code for me" question. Try and fail is acceptable, and it at least shows clearly what you want to do.

Comment: @BlakesSeven i have no  idea how to do it, i'm able to use `InsertManyAsync` in case when i need to insert new documents - it works fine, but how to update many documents with complex update scenario ? I'm able to perform `UpdateOneAsync` but `UpdateDefinition` doesn't cover my needs

Comment: Great big [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32649188/edit) link on your question. Show your failed attempts. Believe me that no-one will laugh. But no effort gains no help from me.

Comment: @BlakesSeven i've added additional information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method "UpdateManyAsync" only works if you want to perform one type of update, which doesn't seem to be your case. What you want to do is perform a Bulk-Update instead. Building on your example, you would want to do something like:

```
        var bulk = new List<WriteModel<Profile>>();
        foreach (Profile item in profiles)
        {
            var newProfile = new Profile2MailList(maillistId, item.MailLists.FirstOrDefault().Status);
            var filter = Builders<Profile>.Filter.Eq(g => g.Id, item.Id);
            var update = Builders<Profile>.Update.AddToSet(item.MailLists, newProfile);
            var updatemodel = new UpdateOneModel<Profile>(filter, update);

            bulk.Add(updatemodel);  
        }
        await profileCollection.BulkWriteAsync(bulk);
```

The AddToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present.